# can't find normal DateTimePicker

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have question, i'm creating project and in them i'm need to create datetimepicker,
standart datetime i can't use because firefox doesn't support this item, jquery i can't use because they didnt work (i guess problem in using jquery items before in my project). Where i can find analogs, please give me some links, or code with example.

Some like this, working only in chrome and IE, but not in firefox :

```
<input type="datetime-local" name="bdaytime">
```

Really thanks all for the help!

Comment: What browser versions are you developing against? [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime) reports no support for `datetime` input in IE11 or lower. (Yes, it's a shame the major vendors are dragging their feet -- Opera had this for years and years now.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use `type="datetime-local"`

Instead use `type="datetime"`

> W3C HTML has dropped input type@datetime-local; "little independent
>   value & source of potential developer confusion"

[Source](https://twitter.com/html5/status/433038890937901056)

Answer (score 0):

Jquery date and timepickers works as charm in all projects. I think, that you have problems with them because of conflicts with other libraries, such as MooTools or prototype.
Read that article about resolving jquery conflicts:
http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/

And as for dateTimepicker, i recommend:
http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/

Also, if you really need clock picker (analog clock), you should try and look for http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Clock-Style-Time-Picker-Plugin-For-Bootstrap-3-clockpicker/